# How do I get an SQLCe sdf databases locale identifier?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to read a database using a connection string like so:

> "Data Source = '" + _SourceDirectory + "'; LCID=SomeLocale"

My issue is when I try to connect to an SDF database I copied from a Windows Mobile device I get the error that the Locale ID is not supported (-1 when I don't specify one). I need to be able to open the database and read from it.

Any ideas?

Comment: a) Which language is used on the Windows Mobile Device?

Comment: a) Which language is used on the Windows Mobile Device?
b) Which OS Version is installed on the Windows Mobile Device?
c) Which SQL Server Compact Edition is used on device and desktop?

Here is a list of supported locale with SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835499%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I 'fixed' this, the SDF file may have been corrupt since after I grabbed a fresh one from the device it worked without issue.